# Problem with Big Sur 11.0.1 and PC/SC library

Tags: java, pcsc, macos-big-sur

I have a problem with the newest version of macOS (BigSur 11.0.1) and the library PC/SC; before BigSur the program the uses the library worked fine but after the update isn't working anymore. I am using the java version 1.8.0_271

In the code, I use the method `TerminalFactory.getDefaultType()` to get the default type of Terminal Factory. Before the update I was receiving "PC/SC" but after the update I am receiving None.

If I want force to connect to an instance with this line

`TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getInstance("PC/SC", null);`

It will return the following error:

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: PC/SC, provider: SunPCSC, class: sun.security.smartcardio.SunPCSC$Factory)
at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1711)
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:243)
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:190)
at javax.smartcardio.TerminalFactory.getInstance(TerminalFactory.java:245)
at prueba.Prueba.isConnected(Prueba.java:165)
at prueba.Prueba.main(Prueba.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: PC/SC not available on this platform
at sun.security.smartcardio.PCSC.checkAvailable(PCSC.java:46)
at sun.security.smartcardio.SunPCSC$Factory.<init>(SunPCSC.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1703)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No PC/SC library found on this system
at sun.security.smartcardio.PlatformPCSC.getLibraryName(PlatformPCSC.java:122)
at sun.security.smartcardio.PlatformPCSC.access$000(PlatformPCSC.java:43)
at sun.security.smartcardio.PlatformPCSC$1.run(PlatformPCSC.java:64)
at sun.security.smartcardio.PlatformPCSC$1.run(PlatformPCSC.java:60)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.security.smartcardio.PlatformPCSC.<clinit>(PlatformPCSC.java:60)
at sun.security.smartcardio.SunPCSC$Factory.<init>(SunPCSC.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1703)
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:243)
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:190)
at javax.smartcardio.TerminalFactory.getInstance(TerminalFactory.java:245)
at javax.smartcardio.TerminalFactory.<clinit>(TerminalFactory.java:106)
at prueba.Prueba.isConnected(Prueba.java:164)
... 1 more
entro isConnected--2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at prueba.Prueba.isConnected(Prueba.java:173)
at prueba.Prueba.main(Prueba.java:63)
```

I found that Big Sur eliminates the library PC/SC and it is no possible to install it.

I don´t know if there is someone with the same error or someone that has already fix it.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Best I could find: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/657267

Comment: @JorgeCampos Yes, I've already seen this post, but I don't use the filesystem dlopen(3) that is explain in the forum.

Answer (score 8):

Because of the changes in macOS Big Sur, Java PC/SC implementation no longer works correctly:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8255877

The workaround is to set the system property:
`sun.security.smartcardio.library=/System/Library/Frameworks/PCSC.framework/Versions/Current/PCSC`

before trying to use `TerminalFactory`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer saved me a lot of time.

Comment: can you explain the solution, because it does not work for me...do you set the system prop in the console ?

Comment: in fact the PCSC exec exist on my pro with sierra but not on air with bigsur

Comment: @GCamel either with `java -Dproperty=value` option or `System.setProperty()` in a static initializer.

Comment: fyi, java -Dproperty=value in the bash is working !

Comment: `System.setProperty("sun.security.smartcardio.library", "/System/Library/Frameworks/PCSC.framework/Versions/Current/PCSC");` This work for me!

Comment: Adding `-Dsun.security.smartcardio.library=/System/Library/Frameworks/PCSC.framework/PCSC` works on BigSur and JDK 14